# How do I give a player a score if they have an item in their inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a tag game with a simple concept, whoever has a name tag named "Tagged" has a score on the scoreboard. Is there a way to do this in 1.13.2? (the objective on the scoreboard is called "tagged")

Comment: Maybe you can use something from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212600/using-testfor-in-minecraft-to-check-if-a-player-has-a-certain-item-in-their-inv), but the solutions there aren't very good. You can do much better in 1.13. I'll write an answer when I have time.

Comment: @Zuma I have updated my answer to be correct. Does it help you in your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
execute as @a store result score @s tagged run clear @s name_tag{display:{Name:"\"Tagged\""}} 0
```

I don't use the `store` function in `execute` very often and I haven't tested it, but this should do it.