# How can I add a count to this command:

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to add a count of 3 to this command :
`/execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}]`

**Edit:** Some may think that this question is a duplicate, but my question is different from [How to test for minimum amount of items in inventory and execute a command if true](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354315/how-to-test-for-minimum-amount-of-items-in-inventory-and-execute-a-command-if-tr).

The linked question uses tellraw while this one uses an execute command. Someone might need to add a run command and /execute has this built-in.

Comment: The linked answer also uses /execute. Combining the information given there, it seems you can produce a command based on your specific demands.

Comment: If you're asking how to do it in one command, it cannot be done. You can only check for a specific amount of items in one slot with nbt. You have to do the multi-command process involving /clear listed in the post linked.