# How would I remove an exact amount of named items from a users inventory on MCBE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to remove exactly 5 sunflowers from a user's inventory, and if they have less than 5 the transaction will not go through, I know a long way of doing it, but the ammount of command blocks is absurd... help!

Comment: This is the solution for Minecraft Java, it will certainly be different in MCPE, but the core idea might be the same: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354315/how-to-test-for-minimum-amount-of-items-in-inventory-and-execute-a-command-if-tr/354386#354386

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test for minimum amount of items in inventory and execute a command if true](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354315/how-to-test-for-minimum-amount-of-items-in-inventory-and-execute-a-command-if-tr)