# How to gave Count into some number or More for @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"things id",Count:Count}}] in java minecraft 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was doing shop into java minecraft 1.14, but scoreboard didn't work on me. I get an idea to write command:

```
/give @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:20b}}] diamond_pickaxe{Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:300}]}
```

(Im not gonna want to do that unbreakable or set efficiencys level into 32767 because its too lagy for my computer) But 20b gets count work only with 20. I want to get it work in 20 or More. I have same button activating

```
/clear @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:20b}}]gold_ingot 20
```

But it dont work in more at 20. How i get that working with 20 or more?

PS. Now i just started using villager. You can guestion same thing on answers, if you need help with it.

Comment: You can remove Count:20b and it will work with any number of gold ingots but then you have to perform some calculations to know how many pickaxes to give to the player.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to test for minimum amount of items in inventory and execute a command if true](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354315/how-to-test-for-minimum-amount-of-items-in-inventory-and-execute-a-command-if-tr)

Comment: The second half of my answer there is your answer.

Comment: MegaCrafter10 That works when doing something whats cost was just 1, but not into everything whats cost is bigger

Comment: Fabian Röling I get idea to give there into cost 20 to That "How to test for mininum amount of items..." :-D. I just dont get the scoreboard working into my computer.