# check for 3 or more blocks in inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I need to check for three or more cobblestone in a player's inventory using command blocks,
I know how to check for the exact amount but not or more. let's say the player has 3 cobblestone in their inventory, the command "`execute at @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:cobblestone",Count:3b}]}] run say hi`" works great, but if the player has 10 it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test for minimum amount of items in inventory and execute a command if true](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354315/how-to-test-for-minimum-amount-of-items-in-inventory-and-execute-a-command-if-tr)

Answer (score 0):

We are going to make it so it clears three cobblestone from their inv. If it’s successful we give them back the three stone and execute a command

First set a command block with the code:

/clear @p cobblestone 3

Then place a conditional chain with the code:

/give @p cobblestone

Place another chain condition command block with the code of your choice

That’s it!

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what your preferences are so I just put down an example.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to check for 3 or more Cobble in the players inventory

Comment: Wait, I think I just found an error in the command. Because what the code listed is doing is also taking it the cobblestone and not giving it back. I will add a new answer later but it will have to use /scoreboard

Comment: /give @p oak_sign{BlockEntityTag: {Text1: "{\"text\":\"You Pay   You Get\",\"italic\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"scoreboard players set @p SHOP 1\"}}",Text2: "{\"text\":\"2x       30x\",\"bold\":true,\"color\":\"white\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/playsound ui.button.click master @a ~ ~ ~ .4 1.7\"}}",Text3: "{\"text\":\"line 3\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute if @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:\"minecraft:cobblestone\",Count:2b}]}] run say U got items\"}}"}, display:{Name: "Bank Sign"}} 1

Comment: I tried this the first two lines work, the third however does not.