# How do I execute a command when a player has greater than or equal to a certain quantity of item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

`/execute as @p if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:amethyst_shard",Count:9b}]}] run say a`

This command line only works when the player has 9 amethyst shards, so I tried many things such as `Count:>=9b` and `Count:9...999b` but they don't return anything at all.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test for minimum amount of items in inventory and execute a command if true](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354315/how-to-test-for-minimum-amount-of-items-in-inventory-and-execute-a-command-if-tr)

Comment: I don't see where it teaches about counting items on that duplicate, only triggers and score testing.